# Onclick function not working in img tag

Tags: javascript

Onclick function not working in this case:

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.simplypo.ayz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/krakow-
3.png" id="gabi" style="text-align: justify;" onClick="myFunction()" />

<p id="demo">Hi!</p>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("Hi", "Hello");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkdrrmhd/2/

Comment: It's because you've attached the code on the `onLoad` function, click on the cog in the javascript panel to see what I mean [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/GMan134/d66j01jn/). Either add it to the head/body or do `window.myFunction = function etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<img src="http://www.simplypo.ayz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/krakow-3.png" id="gabi" style="text-align: justify;" onClick="myFunction('<h2>Gabriela</h2> tomatoes.121')" />
<div id="text-display">dsadasd
</div>
<p id="demo">Visit Microsoft!</p>

<script>
function myFunction(sample) {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/surajmahajan007/kkdrrmhd/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your code is wrapped in a `window.onload` function by default in JSFiddle. To change that, click the JavaScript settings icon and change it to one of the "No wrap" options

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event listeners:

```js
function replaceContents () {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("Hi", "Hello");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}

document.getElementById('gabi').addEventListener('click', replaceContents);
```

```html
<img src="http://www.simplypo.ayz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/krakow-3.png" id="gabi" style="text-align: justify;" />

<p id="demo">Hi!</p>
```